# can't find add function on shortcut menu for a class

Tags: c++, function, class, visual-c++

I'm using visual c++ 2010 Express and I can add a new class to the project I'm making but I can't add new function(or method) to class I created. Here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adkehdt.aspx) they tells me 
"Open the shortcut menu for the class you want to add a member function to, and then choose Add, Add Function".
But in the short cut menu I get no Add or Add function. Can any one help me to solve this isue?I know I can do everything manually but I would really appreciate it if I could solve this delema.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a wizard to add a new method. Just open the `.h` file containing the class and add the implementation to it. Then, open the `.cpp` file where the implementation will go and add it. Easy!